# How are days of stay calculated for a UK visa?

Tags: uk, tourist-visas, standard-visitor-visas

My arrival in Heathrow is in September 23. So, is September 23 counted as day 1 already?

Comment: Why wouldn’t it be?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is counted as day 1. No doubt about it.  Day 1 is on the date you land(clear immigration) in the U.K.  regardless of the time.